# how to call a 'int' function to a 'void' function

Tags: c++

im trying to print a certain message according to the return value using 2 different functions. when  call the function inside the other is says things are not declared

```
int isMatch(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    if(deck[x1][y1] == deck[x2][y2])
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(deck[x1][y1][0] == deck[x2][y2][0])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(deck[x1][y1][1] == deck[x2][y2][1])
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
void printMatch()
{
    int attempt;

    isMatch(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    if(isMatch() == 2)
    {
        cout << "You have a match!";
        attempt++;
    }
}
```

when i try it like this, it still doesnt work

```
int isMatch(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    if(deck[x1][y1] == deck[x2][y2])
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(deck[x1][y1][0] == deck[x2][y2][0])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(deck[x1][y1][1] == deck[x2][y2][1])
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
void printMatch()
{
    int attempt;

    int isMatch(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);

    if(isMatch() == 2)
    {
        cout << "You have a match!";
        attempt++;
    }
}
```

!!!!!!!!!! UPDATE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
int isMatch(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{

    if(deck[x1][y1] == deck[x2][y2]) /// Checks entire element (_,_)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(deck[x1][y1][0] == deck[x2][y2][0]) /// Checks first element (_, )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(deck[x1][y1][1] == deck[x2][y2][1]) /// Checks second element ( ,_)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
void printMatch()
{
    int attempt = 0; /// increments the users attempts
    int score = 0; /// adds total score

    int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;
    int match = isMatch(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    if (match == 2)
    {
        attempt++;
        score = score + 2;
        cout << "\nYou have a match!"
             << "\nTotal score is: " << score
             << "\nTotal no. of attempts: " << attempt << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (match == 1)
    {
        attempt++;
        score = score + 1;
        cout << "\nYou have a match!"
             << "\nTotal score is: " << score
             << "\nTotal no. of attempts: " << attempt << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this??

Comment: The variables `x1`, `y1` etc in `printMatch()` are not defined.

Comment: [Time to pull out a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), Shay. Your understanding of the basics is weak and needs to be shored up before you get in over your head.

Answer (score 2):

Change your printMatch() function to this:

```
void printMatch(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int attempt;

    int temp = isMatch(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    if(temp == 2)
    {
        cout << "You have a match!";
        attempt++;
    }
}
```

This saves your return value from the `isMatch` function to a variable named `temp`. Use can then use this variable `temp` to test your condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your `printMatch` function. Give this a try

```
void printMatch()
{
    int x1 = 4, y1 = 3, x2 = 2, y1 = 1; //you'll need to define these values in some useful way
    int attempt = 0;

    int match = isMatch(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    if(match == 2)
    {
        cout << "You have a match!";
        attempt++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. With this help i get an error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

Comment: attempt is for something else in my assignment

Comment: why do i need to define the values (x1, etc.) if i only need to use the returned value

Comment: Because you need to pass in values to the function in order for it to work. What do you expect it to compare if you do not provide x1, y1, etc?

Comment: i want to print a certain message according to the return value in 'isMatch' . i called the 'IsMatch' funtction in the printMatch to be able to use the return value. does this help you understand?

Comment: The issue is not my understanding. The issue is that you cannot call the `isMatch` function without four values to utilize in calculations, because that's how the programming language works.

Comment: oh mk mk. so can i just set them equal to 0? it wont affect my function will it?

Comment: It most certainly will. The `isMatch` function in that case will always return 2. It needs to have actual values to use in its comparisons. I think you have deeper issues in your program if these are the kinds of questions coming up.

Comment: SUPER SORRY I GOT IT TO WORK. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: now i have a problem, i dont want my isMatch to always equal 2. If my match = 1 i want it to print something else and it still prints 2. I have updated my question